Raise window when clicking titlebar
Clicking in the titlebar of partially-obscured windows used to always raise them to the top.  Now, nothing happens with most windows... until I either move the window slightly (dragging the titlebar with the mouse) or click in an input field within the body of the window.
This happens with any Window Focus setting.
It seems like raise-on-titlebar-leftclick only happens, now, with gnome-specific apps such as gnome-terminal, gnome-tweaks, etc.  Firefox, Virtualbox clients, Thunderbird and other non-gnome apps do not raise when their titlebar is clicked.
Is it possible to re-enable raise-on-titlebar-leftclick for all windows?
Hereare screenshots of relevant settings.  I notice that there is no option to control what happens with a single-left-click in titlebars!
Settings: Ubuntu Desktop: 
Tweaks: Windows: 
Tweaks: Window Titlebars: 
Ubuntu 23.10
GNOME Shell 45.2
Logged in with "Ubuntu on xorg" session

Are you using the new Wayland or the classic X graphics?

xorg (because wayland does not work reliably with some applications)

I just tried Wayland again; the window-raising problem (also a resizing problem) is not there.  So the problem is only with xorg.   Since it only affects non-gnome windows I suspect an incompatible protocol change made within the gnome world; if that's the case it is unfortunate.

I suggest that you test Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS live booted from a USB drive, and if it works correctly, I suggest that you install this new LTS version. Please backup everything that you cannot afford to lose before you start upgrading/installing the new version. (It is probably less risky to make a fresh new installation because do-release-upgrade might carry the problem from your current system to the new version.)

I'm using 24.04.1 LTS and have the described problem---left clicking on the title bar does not raise a partially obscured window.

I don't have an answer, unfortunately, but suffer from the same frustration. Ubuntu 24.04.1 I haven't found any mechanism to trigger lifting the window.
